# How to determine the values of the parameters for which the system has an infinite set of the solutions? four solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

I mean the system

$$ \begin{cases}
a (x+y)+x^2-y^2=a+x-y, \\
b x y+x^2+y^2-1=0
\end{cases}$$ in $x,y$.
Mathematica 13.1 solves it over the reals by

```
Reduce[{a*(x + y) + x^2 - y^2 - a - x + y == 0,  b*x*y + x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

```
(a < -3 && ((b < -2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (-2 <= b < (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || ((-4 + 2 a^2)/a^2 < b < 
        2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -(1/2) - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -(1/2) - a/2 && (y == a + x || 
             y == 1 - x)) || (-(1/2) - a/2 < x < 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == a + x) || (x > 1/2 - a/2 && y == 1 - x))) || (2 < 
        b < -1 - 
         a && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b == -1 - 
         a && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 
            1 && (y == 1 + a || y == 0)) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b > -1 - 
         a && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))))) || (a == -3 && ((b < -2 && ((x == 
            3/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-14 + 9 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -3 + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == 3/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-14 + 9 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -3 + x))) || (-2 <= b < 14/
        9 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == 14/
        9 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 0) || (x == 3/2 &&
            y == -(3/2)))) || (14/9 < b < 
        2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == 3/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-14 + 9 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -3 + x) || (x == 3/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-14 + 9 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == -3 + x))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < 1 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1 && (y == -2 || y == 0)) || (1 < x < 
            2 && y == 1 - x) || (x == 2 && y == -1) || (x > 2 && 
           y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 3/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-14 + 9 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -3 + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == 3/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-14 + 9 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -3 + x))))) || (-3 < 
    a < -2 && ((b < -2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (-2 <= b < (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || ((-4 + 2 a^2)/a^2 < 
        b < -1 - 
         a && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b == -1 - 
         a && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 
            1 && (y == 1 + a || y == 0)) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (-1 - a < b < 
        2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -(1/2) - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -(1/2) - a/2 && (y == a + x || 
             y == 1 - x)) || (-(1/2) - a/2 < x < 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == a + x) || (x > 1/2 - a/2 && y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))))) || (a == -2 && ((b < -2 && ((x == 
            1 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -2 + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == 1 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -2 + x))) || (-2 <= b < 
        1 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == 
        1 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 && (y == -1 || y == 0)))) || (1 < b < 
        2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -2 + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == 1 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -2 + x))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < 1/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/
            2 && (y == -(3/2) || y == 1/2)) || (1/2 < x < 3/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 3/2 && y == -(1/2)) || (x > 3/2 && 
           y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -2 + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == 1 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == -2 + x))))) || (-2 < 
    a < -1 && ((b < -2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (-2 <= b < (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || ((-4 + 2 a^2)/a^2 < 
        b < -1 - 
         a && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == -1 - 
         a && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 
            1 && (y == 1 + a || y == 0)))) || (-1 - a < b < 
        2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -(1/2) - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -(1/2) - a/2 && (y == a + x || 
             y == 1 - x)) || (-(1/2) - a/2 < x < 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == a + x) || (x > 1/2 - a/2 && y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))))) || (a == -1 && ((b < -2 && ((x == 
            0 && (y == -1 || y == 1)) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == -2 && ((x < 0 && 
           y == -1 + x) || (x == 0 && (y == -1 || y == 1)) || (x > 0 &&
            y == -1 + x))) || (-2 < b < 
        2 && ((x == 0 && (y == -1 || y == 1)) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < 0 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 0 && (y == -1 || y == 1)) || (0 < x < 
            1 && y == 1 - x) || (x == 1 && y == 0) || (x > 1 && 
           y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == 0 && (y == -1 || y == 1)) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))))) || (-1 < a < 
    0 && ((b < (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || ((-4 + 2 a^2)/a^2 < 
        b <= -2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (-2 < 
        b < -1 - 
         a && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b == -1 - 
         a && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 && (y == 0 || y == 1 + a)))) || (-1 - 
         a < b < 2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -(1/2) - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -(1/2) - a/2 && (y == a + x || 
             y == 1 - x)) || (-(1/2) - a/2 < x < 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == a + x) || (x > 1/2 - a/2 && y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))))) || (a == 
    0 && ((b <= -2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (-2 < 
        b < -1 && ((x == -Sqrt[(1/(2 + b))] && y == x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 0) || (x == Sqrt[1/(2 + b)] && 
           y == x))) || (b == -1 && ((x == -1 && y == -1) || (x == 0 &&
            y == 1) || (x == 1 && (y == 0 || y == 1)))) || (-1 < b < 
        2 && ((x == -Sqrt[(1/(2 + b))] && y == x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == Sqrt[1/(2 + b)] && y == x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -(1/2) && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -(1/2) && (y == -(1/2) || 
             y == 3/2)) || (-(1/2) < x < 1/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/2 && y == 1/2) || (x > 1/2 && 
           y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == -Sqrt[(1/(2 + b))] && y == x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == Sqrt[1/(2 + b)] && y == x) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))))) || (0 < a < 
    1 && ((b < (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || ((-4 + 2 a^2)/a^2 < 
        b <= -2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (-2 < 
        b < -1 - 
         a && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (b == -1 - 
         a && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 && (y == 0 || y == 1 + a)))) || (-1 - 
         a < b < 2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -(1/2) - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -(1/2) - a/2 && (y == a + x || 
             y == 1 - x)) || (-(1/2) - a/2 < x < 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == a + x) || (x > 1/2 - a/2 && y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))))) || (a == 
    1 && ((b < -2 && ((x == -1 && y == 0) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == -2 && ((x < 1 && 
           y == 1 + x) || (x == 1 && (y == 0 || y == 2)) || (x > 1 && 
           y == 1 + x))) || (-2 < b < 
        2 && ((x == -1 && y == 0) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -1 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -1 && (y == 0 || y == 2)) || (-1 < x <
             0 && y == 1 - x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x > 0 && 
           y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == -1 && y == 0) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))))) || (a > 
    1 && ((b < -1 - 
         a && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 1 && y == 0))) || (b == -1 - 
         a && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && 
           y == 1) || (x == 1 && (y == 0 || y == 1 + a)))) || (-1 - 
         a < b < -2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x))) || (-2 <= b < (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == (-4 + 2 a^2)/
        a^2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] &&
            y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || ((-4 + 2 a^2)/a^2 < b < 
        2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && 
           y == 0))) || (b == 
        2 && ((x < -(1/2) - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == -(1/2) - a/2 && (y == a + x || 
             y == 1 - x)) || (-(1/2) - a/2 < x < 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == 1 - x) || (x == 1/2 - a/2 && 
           y == a + x) || (x > 1/2 - a/2 && y == 1 - x))) || (b > 
        2 && ((x == -(a/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == -(a/2) + 
             1/2 Sqrt[(4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b)/(2 + b)] && 
           y == a + x) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 0)))))
```

As we see, the result is huge. Because of this reason it is difficult to answer the question  about the number of the solutions by eye. The question is: how to do it programmatically? Maple has the [RootFinding[Parametric]](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=RootFinding/Parametric) package to this end.

Comment: `FullSimplify` does not help here.

Comment: @flinty: Your edit of the title distorted the meaning of the question. I restored the original title.

Comment: determinate isn't the right word - please fix it. It's an adjective, not a verb - you want "determine".

Comment: @flinty: See [that](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-ukrainian/To+determinate).

Comment: that's a Ukrainian translation. There's no such thing as 'To determinate' - it's not a verb. [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/determinate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/determinate)

Answer (score 10):

I'll handle dimensionality over the complexes since that's simpler, and provides an important step for finding non-generic cases (fewer than 4, or infinitely many) over the reals. Then I'll show how to start on the real solutions counting.

The point of attack is called the "discriminant variety". In relatively simple cases it can be found computationally as follows.

(1) Construct a Groebner basis for the system, treating parameters as coefficients (rather than variables).

(2) Find conditions on the parameters for which either leading coefficients, or entire polynomials, vanish.

```
polys = {a*(x + y) + x^2 - y^2 - a - x + y, b*x*y + x^2 + y^2 - 1};
vars = {x, y};
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, vars, CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions]

(* Out[1024]= {(1 - a^2) y + (-1 + 2 a + a^2 + a b) y^2 + (-2 - 2 a - b -
      a b) y^3 + (2 + b) y^4, 
 1 - 2 a + a^2 + b - 
  a b + (-1 + 2 a - a^2 - b + a b) x + (1 - a^2 + 2 a b + 
     a b^2) y + (-2 + 2 a - 3 b - a b - b^2 - a b^2) y^2 + (2 b + 
     b^2) y^3} *)
```

First we investigate the polynomial in `y` only.

```
lcoeffy = Coefficient[gb[[1]], y^Exponent[gb[[1]], y]];
Solve[lcoeffy == 0]

(* Out[1052]= {{b -> -2}} *)
```

When `b = 2` the `y` polynomial loses a term and the number of solutions either drops or becomes infinite depending on what happens to the other polynomial.

Let's see when the entire polynomial vanishes.

```
allYcoeffs = CoefficientList[gb[[1]], y];
Solve[allYcoeffs == 0, {a, b}]

(* Out[1036]= {{a -> -1, b -> -2}, {a -> 1, b -> -2}} *)
```

When either of these are satisfied we have no conditions on `y` so the solution set is one dimensional (with `x` parametrized by `y`, which can take on any value) or, if the `x` leading term in the second basis polynomial also vanishes, all of `C^2`.

Next we check what happens when the coefficient for the polynomial that determines `x` vanishes.

```
lcoeffx = Coefficient[gb[[2]], x^Exponent[gb[[2]], x]];
nox = Solve[lcoeffx == 0]
Map[Solve[# == 0, y] &, gb /. nox]

(* Out[1049]= {{a -> 1}, {b -> -1 + a}}

Out[1050]= {{{y -> 0}, {y -> 1}, {y -> 1}},
  {{y -> 0}, {y ->  1}, {y -> -1 + a}}} *)
```

We get in each case a solution for `y`, with `x` allowed to take on any value (so a one-dimensional solution set).

To take this further and count over reals, one might look into the discriminant variety of the first basis polynomial as a function of those parameters. Real solution counts can only change when solution pairs cross and, for this to happen, that variety must vanish.

```
ydiscrim = Discriminant[gb[[1]], y]

(* Out[1053]= (-1 + a)^4 (1 + a)^2 (2 + b) (4 - 8 a + 2 a^2 + 4 a^3 - 
   2 a^4 + 8 b - 8 a b - 3 a^2 b + 2 a^3 b + a^4 b + 4 b^2 - 
   2 a^3 b^2 + a^2 b^3) *)
```

So one can proceed from here by looking at the regions in real parameter space that are demarcated by this zero set.

```
fax = 
 Times @@ 
  Rest[FactorList[(-1 + a)^4 (1 + a)^2 (2 + b) (4 - 8 a + 2 a^2 + 
        4 a^3 - 2 a^4 + 8 b - 8 a b - 3 a^2 b + 2 a^3 b + a^4 b + 
        4 b^2 - 2 a^3 b^2 + a^2 b^3)]][[All, 1]]

(* Out[1055]= (-1 + a) (1 + a) (-1 + a - b) (2 + b) (4 - 2 a^2 + a^2 b) *)

zset = ContourPlot[fax == 0, {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

--- edit ---
I thought I should put in a better graphic.

```
zset = ContourPlot[fax == 0, {a, -5, 5},
  {b, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

--- end edit ---

Comment: Seems I posted anew rather than editing. Deleted first version.

Comment: +1.  Nice. However , you don't completely describe the values of the parameters for which the set of the solutions is infinite. This is not only `{{a -> -1, b -> -2}, {a -> 1, b -> -2}} `. How about four solutions?

Comment: @user64494 Re infinite solutions: It is the union of that set and the one given by Out[1049] (which tells when there is no determined value of `x` so it can take on any value).

Comment: @user 64494 From the Groebner basis (or other general theory), there are four complex solutions, counting multiplicity, every where off the (complex) discriminant variety. That's the set where one or both leading coefficients vanish. Stated differently, neither lead coefficient vanishing implies four solutions.

Comment: We live in the real domain, where `{{a -> 1}, {b -> -1 + a}}` is not true.

Comment: @user64494 That's an either-or situation. Either `a=1` or `b=a-1` causes a change in the count to infinite by removing the leading coefficient in `x` from the second basis polynomial.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand it, as well as `fax`.  I repeat that `{{a -> 1}, {b -> -1 + a}}` is not a complete answer in the case you consider i.e. infinite set of solutions. If you think `fax` is the answer, then it is not true. The answer is simple and can be derived in an elementary way.

Comment: DanielLichtblau (@ does not work.): I am somewhat troubled by no reply of you. Are you OK?

Comment: (1) @ does work. But if you don't use it, I won't see the message. (2) I don't actually read MSE all day. And I don't get email notifications about comments. (3) It is quite possible I made a mistake in the analysis. Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: In this example setting the leading coefficient in the second polynomial to zero does not create an infinite solution set. But it does create one where there are fewer than 4 solutions.

Comment: @user64494 I'm not sure what you are claiming about `fax`. It is simply a way of simplifying the real discriminant variety. It is not related (other than by accident) to the complex discriminant variety. It shows boundaries (in real parameter space) at which the number of real solutions can change.

Comment: @DanielLichblau: Thank you. I understood `fax`. Corollary: you partially answered the first part of the question.

Answer (score 10):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {a*(x + y) + x^2 - y^2 - a - x + y == 0,
   b*x*y + x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0};

sol = Solve[eqns, {x, y}, Reals];

Length@sol

(* 4 *)

eqns /. sol // Simplify
```

[image]

The solutions are conditionally valid.

For there to be four solutions, all of the conditions in the [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)s must be met simultaneously.

```
cond = Reduce[
   And @@
    Cases[sol,
     ConditionalExpression[_, cond_] :> cond, Infinity],
   {a, b}, Reals] //
  Simplify

(* ((2 + b < 0 || 
     1 + a + b > 0 || (4/a^2 + b > 2 && 1 + a + b < 0)) && (a < -2 || -2 < 
      a < -1)) || ((4/a^2 + b < 2 || 
     1 + a + b > 0 || (2 + b > 0 && 1 + a + b < 0)) && (-1 < a < 0 || 
     0 < a < 1)) || (a > 
    1 && (4/a^2 + b > 2 || 1 + a + b < 0 || (2 + b < 0 && 1 + a + b > 0))) *)

sol2 = Assuming[cond, Solve[cond && And @@ eqns, {x, y}, Reals] //
   Simplify]

(* {{x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, 
  y -> 0}, {x -> 1/2 (-a - Sqrt[(4 + a^2 (-2 + b))/(2 + b)]), 
  y -> 1/2 (a - Sqrt[(4 + a^2 (-2 + b))/(2 + b)])}, {x -> 
   1/2 (-a + Sqrt[(4 + a^2 (-2 + b))/(2 + b)]), 
  y -> 1/2 (a + Sqrt[(4 + a^2 (-2 + b))/(2 + b)])}} *)

eqns /. sol2 // Simplify

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

The region for four solutions is

```
RegionPlot[cond, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {a, b})]
```

[image]

For example,

```
sol3 = Solve[eqns /. #, {x, y}] & /@
 {{a -> -2, b -> -3}, {a -> 4, b -> -9/2},
  {a -> -3, b -> 7/2}, {a -> 1/2, b -> 1/2}}

(* {{{x -> -1, y -> -3}, {x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> 3, 
   y -> 1}}, {{x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> -2 - Sqrt[10], 
   y -> 2 - Sqrt[10]}, {x -> -2 + Sqrt[10], y -> 2 + Sqrt[10]}}, {{x -> 0, 
   y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> 1/22 (33 - Sqrt[385]), 
   y -> 1/22 (-33 - Sqrt[385])}, {x -> 1/22 (33 + Sqrt[385]), 
   y -> 1/22 (-33 + Sqrt[385])}}, {{x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, 
   y -> 0}, {x -> 1/20 (-5 - Sqrt[145]), 
   y -> 1/20 (5 - Sqrt[145])}, {x -> 1/20 (-5 + Sqrt[145]), 
   y -> 1/20 (5 + Sqrt[145])}}} *)

Length /@ sol3

(* {4, 4, 4, 4} *)
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for your work. First, `Solve` may do non-equivalent transforms, `Reduce` may not. Second, can you comment you code? A good code is a commented code.

Comment: BTW, Maple splits the parametric plane into 13 sets: for the interiors of 10 ones there are four solutions.

Comment: Your result coincides with the Maple's result. How about the case of infinite sets of the solutions?

Comment: Can you kindly explain how to find parameters for three solutions instead of four solutions?

Comment: That is a significantly different question and should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: BobHanlon (@ does not work.): As far as I understand  it, `Solve` produces a generic solution  in your code. It's unclear to me how to determinate where the number of the solutions equals one/ two/three and so on, modifying your code. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer to the first part of the question: when the system has an infinite set of its solutions? The system `{a*(x + y) + x^2 - y^2 - a - x + y == 0,  b*x*y + x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0}` is equivalent to `x+y-1==0&&b*x*y + x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0||x-y+a==0&&b*x*y + x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0`. Then

```
Reduce[x + y - 1 == 0 && b*x*y + x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> `((b < 2 && (x == 0 || x == 1)) ||  b == 2 || (b > 2 && (x == 0 || x == 1))) && y == 1 - x`

brings `b==-2` and `a` - an arbitrary real number. From the second system `{{a -> -1, b -> -2}, {a -> 1, b -> -2}}` is derived.